# how to get count of visit_status column joing with salesman

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch the count of column name `salesman_activities.visit_status` and I joined with two tables `transactions` and `salesman` and the result is incorrect.

salesman table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `salesman` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

transactions table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `total_amount` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

routes_activities table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `salesman_activities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visit_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and this mysql query

```sql
SELECT
    `transactions`.`driver_id`,
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN `salesman_activities`.`visit_status` = "Productive" AND DATE(`salesman_activities`.`created_at`) BETWEEN '2020-12-17' AND '2020-12-17' THEN `salesman_activities`.`visit_status`
    END
) AS productive_count,
SUM(
        CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 1 THEN `transactions`.`total_amount`
    END
) AS sales,
SUM(
        CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 2 THEN `transactions`.`total_amount`
    END
) AS sales_return

FROM
    `salesman`
INNER JOIN `salesman_activities` ON
        `salesman_activities`.`driver_id` = `salesman`.`driver_id`
INNER JOIN `transactions` ON `transactions`.`driver_id` = `salesman`.`driver_id`
WHERE salesman.id = 14 AND transactions.status = 3
AND DATE(`transactions`.`created_at`) BETWEEN '2020-12-17' AND '2020-12-17'
```

I don't know why is coming incorrect? any help

**note:**
when I remove the join of `salesman_activities` other things are working fine.

Comment: Removed sql server tag - this is not tsql and you specifically mention "mysql query". Pease tag correctly.

Comment: Where is the column `status` in the table `transactions` that you use in the WHERE clause?

Comment: it already exists in my database table, but I forget to mention it on a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `salesman` --> `transaction` and `salesman` --> `salesman_activities` have 1 to many relationship.

Try to use subquery as follows:

```
SELECT `transactions`.`driver_id`,
        sa.productive_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 1 THEN `transactions`.`total_amount`
             END ) AS sales,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 2 THEN `transactions`.`total_amount`
             END) AS sales_return     
  FROM `salesman`
  INNER JOIN 
      (select driver_id, 
              COUNT(CASE WHEN `salesman_activities`.`visit_status` = "Productive" AND DATE(`salesman_activities`.`created_at`) BETWEEN '2020-12-17' AND '2020-12-17' THEN `salesman_activities`.`visit_status`
                     END) AS productive_count
         From `salesman_activities`
         Group by driver_id) sa ON sa.`driver_id` = `salesman`.`driver_id`
  INNER JOIN `transactions` ON `transactions`.`driver_id` = `salesman`.`driver_id`
  WHERE salesman.id = 14 
    AND transactions.status = 3
    AND DATE(`transactions`.`created_at`) BETWEEN '2020-12-17' AND '2020-12-17'
```

Comment: Thank you @Popeye great job :)